# Texshop maximizing and minimizing windows in structured document

Tags: texshop

I hope this is not out of scope of tex.sx: I use the version 2.46 of TeXShop (with Lion) and I recently started structuring my document in various scripts linking them to the main `.tex` file with  the header `%!TEX root = ./main.tex`.

This works fine except that whenever opening one such "subfile", TeXShop also opens and then minimizes the `main.tex` file.

To make things clearer, here's a simple example.

**File main.tex**

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt,twopage,openright]{book}

\begin{document}

\vspace*{\fill}
\begin{center}
This is the main document.
\end{center}
\vfill

\include{chap-tools}

\end{document}
```

**File chap-tools.tex**

```
%!TEX root = ./main.tex

\chapter{Tools}

Some text.
```

Now say that everything is closed and that I open the file `chap-tools.tex` then Texshop will also open and minimize the file `main.tex`. (it also happens on other, yet similar, situations)

It might seem stupid but it drives me crazy!

I was wondering if other users had encountered the same problem and whether they had found a workaround (I tried my luck in the preference pane of Texshop but in vain...).

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Purely a guess, but I'd expect TeXshop does this so that the build button works correctly: i.e., it builds the main file regardless of which file you hit the build button on. That would also make it easier to bring up the main PDF after the build. I don't think there's any facility for it to bring up the main PDF alone.

Comment: Did you try this out with TeXShop 3.10? Does it produce the same phenomenon?

Comment: @brian-ammon thanks! It doesn't solve the problem but +1 anyway as I wasn't aware that there was a specific version for Lion! ``:)``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Edit**

I actually found the source of this problem. I was writing

```
%!TEX root = ./main.tex
```

changing to

```
%!TEX root = main.tex
```

removes the problem...

Answer (score 0):

- Go to Texshop preferences -- Miscellaneous. Then, under Project Root File:
- Deselect the option "Miniaturize the open root window"

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Comment: Thank you. I added this since tibL's TEX root solution does not always work.